# Where can I find the implementation of Selenium Interfaces?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

Maybe a dumb question, but where can I find the implementation of Selenium Interfaces. For example, WebElement is an interface that has a click() method amongst others. Where can I find how Selenium has implemented this click()? There should be an implementation of this interface somewhere. I can't seem to find it.

Another example, Alert. We conveniently switch to an Alert and getText() or dismiss(). But where can I find exactly what selenium is doing under the hood with these functions.

Thanks much!

Comment: WebDriver is implemented by `RemoteWebDriver` class and other classes exten nd from it. `WebElement` on the other hand is not implemented via classes but via `Proxy`

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for this?
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium

For example Webdriver implementation
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#L49

Comment: What you have provided for the WebDriver is the interface. It's not the implementation. There should be some mechanism by which these interfaces are extended and implemented somewhere.